# Does document.getElementById() consider temporarily created DIV

Tags: javascript

I have a DIV like this

```
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = "<div id='a'></div>";
```

And I have not appended it to document yet.. But I just want to retrieve the element `a` from temporary DIV..

I have this way otherwise

```
 div.style.display = "none";
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 // then
 var a = document.getElementById('a');
```

Is there any other better solution for this..?

Comment: You should tell us *why* you want to do this. Most likely there is another solution for your real problem.

Comment: Why close ? No other ways on earth to do without querySelector(), which is not supported in all browsers..?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector) which is also applicable to elements instead of just the whole document:

```
var el = div.querySelector( '#a' );
```

[Browser support is decent.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

Comment: +1, even though 'div' returns the same thing by itself... I'm thinking the question's incomplete :D

Comment: @nevelis Are you sure? OP creates two divs in his code: `<div><div id="a"></div></div>`. So there should be a difference, whether you refer to the outer or inner `<div>`.

Comment: You're absolutely right; I tested querySelector and misread the output, so I didn't post the answer..  time for some sleep, I think!